# Problem Cannot resolve symbol 'DrawableRes' in AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android

i'm new to android and i have this problem in AutocomplettextView Activity it says Cannot resolve symbol 'DrawableRes'

```
import android.annotation.DrawableRes;
```

this is my list of dependencies `

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.4.0'
implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.18.0'
implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.18.0') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-traffic:0.6.0'
implementation 'com.fxn769:cue:1.1'
implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1"
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:3.4.1'

//retrofit2
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

//RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
implementation files('libs/usbserial.jar')
```

and this one has a problem also

```
 implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
```

it says "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion)."

Comment: `import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;`.

Comment: still have the same problem

Comment: What is your target sdk?

Comment: my target is 27 and min sdk is 21

Comment: Should line `4` and `6` be the same version?

Answer (score 0):

intead of implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"

use  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"

and change implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"

to implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
```

with

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
```

and add these 2 dependencies to the Gradle file

```
implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1"
```

Comment: thank you, the problem with dependencies is gone but still have this DrawabelRes issue

Comment: Try replacing `import android.annotation.DrawableRes;`  with `import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;`

Comment: There are no more issues with your Gradle file right? If so, can you also share the code from your activity

Comment: Also, can you share a screenshot of your sdk screen? Which displays all the build tools installed

Comment: Neeraj i responded to your comment in an answer cause i cant upload image here